# Why does tapping a TTY device only capture every other character?

Tags: devices, tty

So, I came across the `ttyname` function (*unistd.h*) and had to test it out.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  printf("%s\n", ttyname(0));
  return 0;
}
```

On my machine, it echos out `/dev/ttys011`. I discovered it's a device!

```
echo "Hello" > /dev/ttys011
```

Woah, running that from another terminal produced *Hello* in the original terminal I ran my `ttyname` program in.

So what happens when I `cat /dev/ttys011`? Well, I get **every other character** typed. Oh yeah; it breaks the original TTY session, too.

So I try the following:

```
cat /dev/ttys011 | tee /dev/ttys011
```

Well, everything *shows up* in the original terminal, but my "tap" terminal (the one the above command is being run in) is still only getting **every other character**.

Oh yeah, my original terminal is still broken (the characters show up, but only every other character actually reaches my shell).

For instance, typing `ls` yields `ls` in the terminal, `l` in the "tap" terminal, and running it gives me `'l' is not a command`.

What is going on here? I would expect weird behavior, but why is **every other character** being captured?

Comment: See also [In OS X Darwin, why can I interfere with text input across user sessions using cat?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118873/in-os-x-darwin-why-can-i-interfere-with-text-input-across-user-sessions-using-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shell, or whatever process was in the foreground, was already reading the terminal to which is was attached, which was `/dev/ttys011`. Then you started another process, a `cat` *also* reading the same terminal at the same time.

Now there are two processes competing for the same input from the terminal. Each time you type a key in the terminal, it is delivered to one of the waiting processes. The other process is interested in reading too, but when it becomes its turn to read there's nothing left to read. Even though you seemed to observe a regular alternation of which characters go to which process, it's actually unpredictable which parts of the input will go to which process: it could be all input to one, all input to the other, or anything in between.

If you want your `cat` process to receive all of the input, you need to arrange for nothing else to be reading from the same device at the same time. One easy way you could do that is to run something like `sleep 999` in the terminal. `sleep` waits for the delay to expire, but while it's waiting it shouldn't be attempting to read anything.

The command:

```
cat /dev/ttys011 | tee /dev/ttys011
```

does not restore any input captured by `cat` to its original location. That is, `tee` does not deliver it to whatever process was originally interested in reading it (such as your shell), it just sends it to the terminal's output, which causes it to be displayed.

By the way: you don't need a C program and the `ttyname()` function to get your terminal's name; all you have to do is type `tty` and press enter at the shell prompt.

Comment: Heh, this makes a *lot* of sense. So TTY's are simply the input sessions? That would make sense, seeing as how `cat` is almost becoming the "shell" of sorts (even though it's not doing anything with the input).

Comment: No, ttys are not just input sessions, they do input **and** output, as you saw when you did `echo "Hello" > /dev/ttys011`. When the tty is a serial port for example the input is connected to the receive line of the serial port and the output is connected to the transmit line. For pseudo-terminals like the one you're talking about, both input and output are connected to a piece of software, like a terminal emulator. Yes, `cat` is becoming the "shell" in the sense that it is taking input from a terminal like shells do. It's no different than what happens when you simply run `cat` at the prompt.

Comment: Actually, now that I'm re-reading this; I don't think it's random or unpredictable; `read()` is usually a blocking call. One blocks, and when a character is read it processes and the second program blocks with a call to `read()`, and back and forth. Still a great answer.

Comment: @Qix it really is unpredictable. In your example, nothing guarantees that the other thread will get scheduled and call `read()` before the first thread calls `read()` again. And while both threads are blocked on `read()`, the kernel does not make any promises about which one it will wake up.

Comment: Ah true, didn't think about that.